# Complex power series exercise

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm stuck in a the following point of an exercise. Consider the following series $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left(1 + \frac{i}{n}\right)^{n^3} z^n,$$

it says that the convergence radius is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$. How can I prove that?

Comment: ERRATA CORRIGE: the series is $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left(1 + \frac{i}{n}\right)^{n^3} z^n$$

Comment: I edit your post for you.

Comment: @Winther i actually dont see how this works, it seems that you have an $ni$ term that will tend to infinity

Comment: @qbert I removed the comment as it was confusingly phrased. See the answer below for a better derivation.

Answer (score 5):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left| a_n\right|^{1/n}&=|z|\,\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\left(1+\frac in\right)^{n^2} \right|\\\\
&=|z|\,\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^{n^2/2}\\\\
&=|z|e^{1/2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you explain the change of variables that allowed you to put $n^2$ in the parentheses?

Comment: @qbert Took the absolute value of the thing.  (absolute value of a complex number is...?)

Comment: The complex number $w=1+\frac in$ has magnitude $$|w|=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}$$

Comment: ah! I see, oops

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Answer (score 1):

We can use the Hadamard criterion. So:

$$\frac{1}{\rho}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n},$$

in your case we have: 
$$\frac{1}{\rho}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{\Big|\Big(1+\frac{i}{n}\Big)^{n^3}\Big|}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Big| \Big(1+\frac{i}{n}\Big)^{n^2}\Big|=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Big| \Big(1+\frac{i}{n}\Big)\Big|^{n^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Big| \Big(\frac{n+i}{n}\Big)\Big|^{n^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Big(\sqrt{\frac{n^2+1}{n^2}}\Big)^{n^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Big( \Big(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)^{n^2}\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{e}.$$

So $\rho=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$.

Comment: First of all, your a little bit late.  And secondly, you should've had the absolute values since the beginning.

Comment: I edit my post, secondly I didn't see the other answer while I was writing.

Comment: Yeah, perfectly fine.  We all do that :D